# logs available on cloudwatch even after stopping the agent on the server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

As part of cloud-watch log cleanup , i stopped the agent on all servers and am deleting the log groups.

Command used:

```
sudo service awslogs stop
```

But the logs appear on the console even after stopping the agent.

Is this an expected behaviour?
How can i delete all the log groups in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The logs aren't going to be automatically deleted just because you stopped sending new log data. You'll have to manually delete them in the web console, use the [AWS CLI tool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/delete-log-group.html).

Comment: after stopping the agent i did delete them but still the log group and stream appears with the latest date.

Comment: If new log data is appearing then you didn't actually stop the agents.